# Right-align chapter/section/subsection header

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

How can I change the alignment of a chapter/section/subsection heading? Preferably, I want this to be something I specify in the header, as this will be necessary for all headers in the document.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can be done using the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

Here's a compilable demonstration example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\justifyheading}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Now the headings are right aligned. I defined a macro `\justifyheading`. If you later wish to left-justify or to center, simply define `\justifyheading` to be `\raggedleft` respctively `\centering`.

[image]

Comment: Just for posterity, this can be done even simpler, just using the "easy setup" technique described on 2 of [the titlesec manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf): just add `\usepackage[raggedleft]{titlesec}` to the header.

Comment: @eykanal: Great, that option really works!

Comment: The option when the package is imported did not work for me but I have also a few definitions using `\titleformat`. I just had to add `\raggedleft` to section and subsection definition.

Answer (score 11):

Just for completeness -- This can also be accomplished with the `sectsty` package:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\raggedleft}
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use a [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html)-class and redefine `\raggedsection`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\raggedleft}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```