# How will I right align the chapter/section/subsection?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Right-align chapter/section/subsection header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/right-align-chapter-section-subsection-header)

I need to align the chapter and its heading to the right. Please help me with it

Comment: Which documentclass do you use: book, memoir, scrbook, or something else?

Comment: I use report. I am writing a thesis

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using a documentclass such as `report` or `book`, you could load the [sectsty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty) package with the command

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
```

and insert the instruction

```
\chapterfont{\raggedleft}
```

in the preamble to get chapter headers to be right-aligned. To get *all* levels of sectioning headers in this style, issue the command

```
\allsectionsfont{\raggedleft}
```

Comment: I use documentclass{report}. How can I install the package? From where will I get the pacakge?

Comment: Dont worry it is not a package.. It is included in the report class already.. Just run it. It should work..

Comment: If you use a TeX distribution such as TeXLive, the `sectsty` package should already be loaded. If you use MiKTeX, its package autoloader should download and install the package the first time it's encountered. I've added an explanation of how to load the `sectsty` package to my answer.

Comment: @royce `sectsty`is not included in the `report`-class. It is a separate package, certainly included in most modern distributions.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot install the `sectsty`-package, you can also hack the definitions of `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
      \par\nobreak
      \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Test}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

The code is borrowed from [Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) and slightly modified.