# centering the chapter title in article class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, article

In an article class:

- How to make the chapter heading centered?
- The command `\section` or `\chapter` is come with the error "undefined control sequence" when it is compiled.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Article does not define `\chapter`. You need to use `report` or a similar class for this.

Comment: Which *article class*? As TeXnician stated, article classes usually does not have `\chapter`, so usually `\chapter` is undefined. How to center section headings depends on the class, e.g., `scrartcl` provides `\raggedsection` that can be set to `\centering`. `memoir` also has its own interface. Other classes may need extra packages. So please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question. And tell us as exact as possible, what you've done and what you expect. BTW: You should ask only one question per question.

Comment: Related: [Underline and center headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26878), [Centering chapter/section/subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107281), [Right-align chapter/section/subsection header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6618), [Section Heading Centering problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546), [How to center chapter, section and subsection using memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214531) and several more.

Answer (score 0):

The `titlesec`package is there for that. This should do it just fine :

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering}
```

Comment: But you should use `titlesec` only, if you use a class to which it is really compatible. `titlesec` is not compatible with all article classes.

Comment: Of course, I assumed a standard class was used